# OneFile Kivy app with Nuitka missing files

Tags: kivy, nuitka

I'm trying to compile a Kivy app to onefile but I'm getting the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~1\main.py", line 192, in <module>
     MainApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~1\kivy\app.py", line 954, in run
   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~1\kivy\app.py", line 923, in _run_prepare
   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~1\kivy\app.py", line 696, in load_kv
   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~1\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 305, in load_file
   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~1\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 407, in load_string
   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~1\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 620, in _apply_rule
   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~1\kivy\factory.py", line 155, in __getattr__
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in __import__
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~1\kivymd\uix\bottomnavigation\__init__.py", line 2, in <module kivymd.uix.bottomnavigation>
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~1\kivymd\uix\bottomnavigation\bottomnavigation.py", line 212, in <module kivymd.uix.bottomnavigation.bottomnavigation>
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ONEFIL~1\\kivymd\\uix\\bottomnavigation\\bottomnavigation.kv'
```

I'm compiling the app using:

`python -m nuitka --onefile  --follow-imports --include-data-file=*.kv=./ main.py`

I can see in the logs when it's being compiled that it's including my main.kv file which uses "MDBottomNavigation".

`Nuitka-Options:INFO: Included data file 'main.kv' due to specified data file '*.kv=./' on command line.`

I've also checked that the main.kv file is being loaded within the app by printing it.

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
    return path.join(path.abspath("."), relative_path)

#printing the correct path here
print(resource_path('main.kv'))

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'MyApp'
        self.icon = resource_path('icon.ico')
        self.version = '1'
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Teal'
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "300"
        Window.bind(on_dropfile=self._on_file_drop)
        return Builder.load_file(resource_path('main.kv'))
```